# Return Sum from another table in join with duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, ansi-sql

I have the following 2 tables:

tblEventCustomers

```
EventCustomerId EventId CustomerId  InvoiceLineId
1002            100     5           21
1003            100     6           21
1004            100     7           22
1005            101     9           23
```

tblInvoiceLines

```
InvoiceLineId   Quantity    Price
21              2           25
22              1           12.5
23              1           34
```

I want to return the number of customers on an event and the total of the invoice lines for that event:

```
EventId     No. Delegates   Total
100         3               37.5
101         1               34
```

I have tried the following function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udfInvoiceLineTotal
(
    @eventId AS INT
)
RETURNS MONEY
BEGIN
    DECLARE @returnAmount AS MONEY;
    SET @returnAmount = (
    select sum(Price) from tblInvoiceLines as IL
    where il.InvoiceLineId in
    (
        SELECT InvoiceLineId
        FROM tblEventCustomers
        where EventId = @eventId
    )   
    )
    RETURN @returnAmount;
END
```

And used it as below:

```
select      ed.EventId, 
            COUNT(1),
            dbo.udfInvoiceLineTotal(ed.EventId) from tblEventCustomers as ED

inner join  tblInvoiceLines as IL
on          IL.InvoiceLineId = ED.InvoiceLineId
group by    ed.EventId
```

This returns me the results I want, however I wanted to see if I was missing any way to do it in a more ANSI SQL way, i.e. using Sub-Queries rather than a database function?

The approach below returns me duplicates in the sum:

```
select  ed.EventId,
        SUM(il.Price),
        COUNT(1)
from    tblEventCustomers as ed
inner join tblInvoiceLines as il
on      ed.InvoiceLineId = il.InvoiceLineId
group by (ed.EventId)
```

### Edit

Apologies for all those who answered, I realise I had a typo in my original data set which meant some of the suggested approaches worked for the dataset I presented at first but don't work for the full data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you modify your last approach like this, it should give you the desired results:

```
select  ed.EventId,
        SUM(il.Price/il.quantity)
from    tblEventCustomers as ed
inner join tblInvoiceLines as il
on      ed.InvoiceLineId = il.InvoiceLineId
group by (ed.EventId)
having COUNT(ed.EventCustomerId) > 5
```

And to include the number of delegates, just add `SUM(il.quantity)`

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work even for the newer version of the dataset in my latest edit. To return the number of delegates ```COUNT(1)``` returned the correct figure (in my new dataset).

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for you?  It gets the results you are looking for

```
SELECT c.EventId, SUM(Quantity), SUM(i.price)
FROM tblInvoiceLines i
   JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT 
         EventId, CustomerId, InvoiceLineId
        FROM tblEventCustomers) c ON i.InvoiceLineId = c.InvoiceLineId
GROUP BY c.EventId
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution worked for the data I originally posted, however I realised that I'd made a stupid error in the data, so this solution no longer returns the correct results, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you'll need a subquery to get rid of what you're calling duplicates, which is being caused by the `EventCustomerId` column, which you're not including.

```
select
  ec.eventid,
  count (ec.CustomerId),
  sum(il.price)

from
  (select
     eventid,
     customerid,
     invoicelineid
   from
     tblEventCustomers
    group by
      eventid,
      customerid,
      invoicelineid)
   EC
inner join tblInvoiceLines IL
  on ec.invoicelineid = il.invoicelineid
group by
  ec.eventid
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d592e/4)

Comment: Thanks for your response, this worked for the dataset I presented in my original question however I (stupidly) made a typo in the CustomerId column so this approach no longer seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pre-aggregate the results before the join.  You can use subqueries for this:

```
select c.EventId, c.NumCustomers, ci.price
from (select c.EventId, count(*) as NumCustomers
      from tblEventCustomers c
      group by c.EventId
     ) c left join
     (select c.EventId, sum(i.price) as price
      from (select distinct EventId, InvoiceLineId
            from tblEventCustomers c
           ) c join
           tblInvoiceLines i
           on i.InvoiceLineId = c.InvoiceLineId
      group by c.EventId
     ) ci
     on c.EventId = ci.EventId;
```

What makes this confusing is that you have to join the customers table to the invoice table to get the event id.

Comment: This returns an error at the second select statement because C.EventId is not included in the aggregate.

Comment: @Underscore . . . That is strange.  There was a blank line in the code instead of the `group by`.  Oh well.  It is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into CTEs (Common Table Expression)  where you pre-calculate/group for one table then join the results with the other table based on a column and display the results all together. It's similar to sub-queries but I like CTE's more because they are easier to read.

see these links as a reference, hope this helps:

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-cte-basics/

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2007/10/18/ctes-common-table-expressions.aspx